# Why the empty space between goods and passengers train is ignored?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ratio of the speeds of a goods train and a passenger train is 3:7. The two trains can cross each other in 40 sec. A man in the passenger train observes that the goods train crosses him in 25 sec. If the goods train is 275m long, what is the length of the passenger
train?

[image]

***I proceed like this***: We have to find Two trains crossing distance because two trains can crossing time is given. So Two trains crossing distance = 275 + X
Other distance will be P’s distance i.e 275m

$$
\begin{split}
&\text{Distance ratio }= (275+X)/275\\
&\text{Time ratio }= 40/25\text{ (given)}\\
&\to (275+X)/275 = 40/25\\
&\to X = 165m
\end{split}
$$

Why the empty space between goods and passengers train is ignored? (I marked with red)

Comment: Please fix the image link.

Comment: I see no red marking.

Comment: The vertical space between the two trains has no bearing on the time it takes for the trains to pass each other.  The statements about the ration of the speeds of the train ad the time it takes to cross. Contain all the information.  Vertical distance between the trains has nothing to do with track and passing speed.

Comment: It's not ignored.  The time the trains meet and passed is calculated based on the moment the start to pass.  And time before that, say a few seconds or a few thousand years isn't relevant to the problem.